# Objective C (iOS): How to retain a variables value even when the view has changed?

Tags: objective-c, variables, static, global-variables

I have 2 ViewControllers (A,B). A presents B and there will be a variable in B which I wish to retain its value even when I dismissed B and went back to A.

I have tried a static variable defined in B and also a getter method. But the returned value is always the same, when I access it from A.

What is the best way to define this variable?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to keep reference to B just because of one variable?

Comment: I don't know any better way of to keep a value persistently. What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: There are quite a few different ways that you could solve this. But the choice depends on specifically what the variable is used for. Can you explain further what the variable represents, and why both controllers depend on it? Also, if you want someone to help you debug your static variable solution, then please post the code.